# Matching Two Separate Javascript Objects based on Properties

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Have a pretty complex use case with Objects and am curious what the right way to do this would be.

Please see example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/upp3px3y/1/

Basically, I have a single object (var object) which has multiple objects inside of it. I then have an array of objects (var returnedData) whose entries are objects. I basically want to match the objects inside returnedData, via the name property to the correct object (inside var object), then add it as a separate property to that object...

The ideal state of the data would be something like:

```
    people: {
        p1: {
            name: "richard",
            nationality: "USA",
            data: {
                 name: "richard",
                 number: "11111",
                 city: "new york"       
            }
        },
        p2: {
            name: "chris",
            nationality: "USA",
            data: {
                 name: "chris",
                 number: "11111",
                 city: "new york"       
            }
        }
    }
```

I haven't seen much documentation and questions on SO as far as being able to work with so many nested objects. I'm not even sure how to approach this problem, so any suggestions are hugely appreciated.

I feel like the answer may have to do with using Object.keys(obj), but I'm not sure what the best way to traverse into an object within another object would be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, I would traverse the array, and check to see if returnedData object name matched any of the names in signup or non-signups, and append if needed.  Did you need help writing that or are you asking if there's a better way then what I just described?

Comment: I know I can loop through the array and get the names from the objects inside of it ...but how would I write the matching portion? Wouldn't it be best to simultaneously append the data while looping through the array? I am also not sure how to go about matching based on "name" property for the objects within objects of signups and nonsignups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop through the array, and try to match each index object's name to one of obj's nested objects.  Here's an example I wrote for you.

Note:  I renamed var object to "obj", since it matches Object too easily.

The top level "For In" is for the upper level "signups, nonsignups" and the nested "For In" is for traversing people.  You need to use bracket notation when using variables for object properties.

JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/upp3px3y/5/

JS:

```
for ( var i = 0; i< returnedData.length; i++) {

    for ( var keys in obj ) {
      if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(keys) ) {    
        for (var propname in obj[keys].people) { 
          if (obj[keys].people.hasOwnProperty(propname)) { 

            if ( obj[keys].people[propname].name === returnedData[i].name ) {

                // when you find a match, add 'data' property and append data object.
                obj[keys].people[propname].data = returnedData[i];
            }

          } 
        } // end for-in
      }
    }  // end for-in
}  // end for
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Didn't realize that [keys] could be used multiple times in that way (how you have a second version as propname). This is awesome. Thanks for the explanation as well. If I could upvote twice I would!